# How to avoid entering duplicate values into table through winform?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

in my project I have set the client name as primary key and if I enter the same value, I will get exception, now I want to write the validation, i.e if I re enter the primary key value then I should get a message like "Data already exists", Please help me to do that, The code I am using to insert value is:

```
      private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (txtName.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Project Name!");
            txtName.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtContactPerson.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Description!");
            txtContactPerson.Focus();
            return;
        }
        SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
        con.Open();
        string commandText = "InsertClient";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", txtContactPerson.Text);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MessageBox.Show("Client details are inserted successfully");
        txtName.Clear();
        txtContactPerson.Clear();
        object Name = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        BindData();            
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: your `InsertClient` procedure doesn't have any `primary key` passed in, looks like the `primary key` is automatically increased such as by using `auto_increment`? Otherwise, what is the actual `primary key` in your inserted record?

Comment: ClientName is the primary key. Auto increment is set to another item client ID which is not a primary key.

Comment: Put a button in a try catch block and post the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your requirement, I see that you are asking about using of your own code instead of the exception. You can get it by using the try catch block. Try the following code:

```
try
{
    object Name = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Client details are inserted successfully");
    txtName.Clear();
    txtContactPerson.Clear();
    BindData();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Handle exception, Inform User
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would tend to allow the user to try to enter any superficially valid primary key, If it is a duplicate then there will be an exception that you can catch and display to the user.

The reason for this is you would have to check the database for an existing key so you might as well do this by trying to insert it and handling any errors.

You could probably improve the validation and error handling a lot more, popping up a message box on every individual problem is annoying, better to have a summary with all the problems. Also holding open a database connection while displaying a message box probably isn't advisable either.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (txtName.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Project Name!");
        txtName.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (txtContactPerson.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Description!");
        txtContactPerson.Focus();
        return;
    }
    SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
    con.Open();
    string commandText = "InsertClient";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", txtContactPerson.Text);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

try
{
    object Name = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Client details are inserted successfully");
    txtName.Clear();
    txtContactPerson.Clear();
    BindData();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
        //Handle exception, Inform User
}
finally
{
        con.Close();
}      
}
```

Comment: I am not getting error, but after I entering the duplicate value, first I am getting MessageBox.Show("Client details are inserted successfully"); and then "Deails already exists message" which I entered in catch block.

Comment: The message box was being shown before you were doing the insert, should show it after. Trying to insert a duplicate primary key will cause an error unless your stored procedure is swallowing it in some way.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can prevent a duplicate from ever occurring in the table by using a unique index or constraint. An index/constraint can work in concert with the suggestions below. If you only use a unique index and not one of the below solutions, inserting a duplicate record will throw an error and you will need to handle that on the other end.

*you could check for the records existence and insert or update manually:*

```
create procedure MyProcedure
(
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    ...
)
as

    if not exists (select * from MyTable where Name = @Name)
    begin
        insert into MyTable (Name,...) values (@Name,...)
    end
    else
    begin
            update MyTable
            set ...
            where Name = @Name
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use Entity Framework as it will throw an exception in this case, however I suppose you could run an sql query first to check whether it exists or not, or though there may be a significant performance overhead with that

Comment: I am sorry, it is not possible to check from the SQL server, normally customer dont have access to database, he can only know it is the primary key when he gets that error only. Mt requirement is customer should get a validation or exception at the execution time only before entering on insert button.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean that the customer should check, I meant an sqlcmd that searches the table on that primary key, then you could check whether any rows were returned and if so throw your own exception. (should have been more clear! :-))